# Getting error by using DevExtreme, SummaryType.Custom

Tags: c#, devextreme

I try to do like on the next example :

https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/Widgetsgallery/Demo/DataGrid/CustomSummaries/NetCore/Light/

I have try to create a custom summary for my grid

For example on the next picture I have the red column and the blue column and I want to summing that as (In pseudo code)

```
Sum = 0;
  if({RedColumn}.Value == D){
      Sum -= {BlueColumn}.Value
   }else{
      Sum += {BlueColumn}.Value
   }
```

[image]

I expected to get  347.74 -218.46 +272.7  =  401.98    and not  838.9

I also create the next method (I know its not finish yet, but I even not get in to this method, I got the error befor) :

```
 function CalculateCustomSummary(options) {
        if (options.name === "SelectedRowsSummary") {
            if (options.summaryProcess === "start") {
                options.CdAmt = 0;
            }
            if (options.summaryProcess === "calculate") {
                options.CdAmt = options.CdAmt + options.value.CdAmt;
            }
        }
    }
```

this is my summery :

```
   .Summary(s => s.GroupItems(items => items.AddFor(t=>t.CdAmt)
                    .Name("SelectedRowsSummary")
                    .ShowInColumn("CdAmt")
                    .DisplayFormat("Sum: {0}")
                    .ValueFormat(Format.Decimal)
                    .SummaryType(SummaryType.Custom)
             ).CalculateCustomSummary("CalculateCustomSummary"))
```

This is my load action on the server side   (.LoadAction("{FuncName}"))

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> {FuncName}(int Id, DataSourceLoadOptions loadOptions ... more params)
{
    try
    {
        IQueryable<X> hzInfos;
        hzInfos = _hService.GetAllHZ();  
        return Json(DataSourceLoader.Load(hzInfos, loadOptions));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _log.LogError($"Method Name: {System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name}, " +
           $"Exception: {ex}");
        return StatusCode(500);
    }
}
```

And on the next line :  `return Json(DataSourceLoader.Load(hzInfos, loadOptions));`

I have got the next error:

"Specified method is not supported."

" at DevExtreme.AspNet.Data.RemoteGrouping.RemoteGroupExpressionCompiler.GetPreAggregateMethodName(String summaryType)\r\n at DevExtreme.AspNet.Data.RemoteGrouping.RemoteGroupExpressionCompiler.MakeAggregate(Expression aggregateTarget, SummaryInfo s)\r\n at DevExtreme.AspNet.Data.RemoteGrouping.RemoteGroupExpressionCompiler.d__8.MoveNext()\r\n at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddEnumerable(IEnumerable`1 enumerable)\r\n at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.InsertRange(Int32 index, IEnumerable`1 collection)\r\n at DevExtreme.AspNet.Data.RemoteGrouping.RemoteGroupExpressionCompiler.MakeAggregatingProjection(Expression target, Type groupingType, AnonTypeFacade groupKeyTypeFacade)\r\n at DevExtreme.AspNet.Data.RemoteGrouping.RemoteGroupExpressionCompiler.Compile(Expression target)\r\n at DevExtreme.AspNet.Data.DataSourceExpressionBuilder.AddRemoteGrouping(Boolean suppressGroups, Boolean suppressTotals)\r\n at DevExtreme.AspNet.Data.DataSourceExpressionBuilder.BuildLoadGroupsExpr(Boolean paginate, Boolean suppressGroups, Boolean suppressTotals)\r\n at DevExtreme.AspNet.Data.DataSourceLoaderImpl`1.<ExecRemoteGroupingAsync>d__13.MoveNext()\r\n at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at DevExtreme.AspNet.Data.DataSourceLoaderImpl`1.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at DevExtreme.AspNet.Data.DataSourceLoader.Load[T](IQueryable`1 source, DataSourceLoadOptionsBase options)\r\n at CardTranzactions.Controllers.HovaZehutSTHZController.d__11.MoveNext() in {the path}

What Can I do about it?

**Change my code in another tries by comment suggestion:**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> {FuncName}(int Id, DataSourceLoadOptions loadOptions ... more params)
    {
        try
        {
            List<X> hzInfos;
            hzInfos = _hService.GetAllHZ().ToList();  
            return Json(DataSourceLoader.Load(hzInfos, loadOptions));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _log.LogError($"Method Name: {System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name}, " +
               $"Exception: {ex}");
            return StatusCode(500);
        }
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
       at DevExtreme.AspNet.Data.Aggregation.AggregateCalculator`1.CreateAggregator(SummaryInfo summaryInfo)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectArrayIterator`2.ToArray()
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at DevExtreme.AspNet.Data.Aggregation.AggregateCalculator`1.ProcessGroup(Group group)
       at DevExtreme.AspNet.Data.Aggregation.AggregateCalculator`1.ProcessItem(Object item)
       at DevExtreme.AspNet.Data.Aggregation.AggregateCalculator`1.Run()
       at DevExtreme.AspNet.Data.DataSourceLoaderImpl`1.<ContinueWithAggregationAsync>d__9`1.MoveNext()
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at DevExtreme.AspNet.Data.DataSourceLoaderImpl`1.<ContinueWithGroupingAsync>d__8`1.MoveNext()
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at DevExtreme.AspNet.Data.DataSourceLoaderImpl`1.<LoadAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at DevExtreme.AspNet.Data.DataSourceLoader.Load[T](IQueryable`1 source, DataSourceLoadOptionsBase options)
       at CardTranzactions.Controllers.HovaZehutSTHZController.<GetHZ>d__11.MoveNext() in {the path}
```

Comment: Instead of using a `IQueriable` use a `List` and tell me the result

Comment: @FilipeNóbrega  Add the result to the end of my question

Comment: I'll post some code bellow tell me if it works

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution, don't return a JSON, just follow the WebApi guide for .Net Core:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<object> {FuncName}(int Id, DataSourceLoadOptions loadOptions ... more params)
{
    try
    {
        return DataSourceLoader.Load(_hService.GetAllHZ(), loadOptions);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _log.LogError($"Method Name: {System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name}, " +
           $"Exception: {ex}");
        return StatusCode(500);
    }
}
```

Also make sure that the `remoteOperations.summary`, `remoteOperations.groupPaging`, or `remoteOperations` property is not set or set to false.

See: https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPNetCore/Demo/DataGrid/WebAPIService/

Comment: the result is the same :(

I make the change you said and also add 
.RemoteOperations(r=>r.Summary(true))
.RemoteOperations(r => r.GroupPaging(true))
.RemoteOperations(true)  on client side

Comment: You have to set them to false

Comment: Is it working without the custom summary?

Comment: yes.   Never mind I just create a class and Inheritance from X and add property that make the custom if (....) return a else return -a   and make a normal sum on that

Thanks for helping me